# Solr Cloud Managed Resources

Tags: solr, solrcloud, synonym, stop-words

I am implementing Solr Cloud for the first time.  I've worked with normal Solr and have that down pretty well, but I'm not finding a lot on what you can and can't do with Solr Cloud.  So my question is about Managed Resources.  I know you can CRUD stop words and synonyms using the new RESTful api in solr.  However with the cloud do I need to CRUD my changes to each individual solr server in the cloud, or do I send them to a different url that sends them through to each server?  I'm new to cloud and zookeeper.  I have not found anything in the solr wiki about working with the managed resources in the cloud setup.  Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What does managed resources mean in above question? And which wiki are you referring to?

Comment: See the updated solr documentation on Managed Resources here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SolrCloud configuration and other files like stopwords, are stored and maintained by Zookeeper. Which means you do not need to individually send updates to each server.

Once you have SolrCloud, before putting in any data, you will create a collection. Each collection has its own set of resources/config folder.

So for example if u have a collection called `techproducts` with 2 servers `localhost1` and `localhost2` the below command from any of the servers will work on the same resource.

```
curl "http://localhost1:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"

curl "http://localhost2:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"
```

Comment: So since both servers can be used, I would assume this is where a load balancer would come into play?  I don't want to have to know which server to send the requests to correct, so the only thing is a load balancer or is there something in zookeeper that gives me a different url to post to?

Comment: Correct. Taking the above example, you can add load balancer in front of these two servers and all requests can then be sent to the single load balancer url. It doesn't matter which SOLR server the load balancer selects.